# htaccess Mask subfolder as root

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website on the root of my domain and I need to show everything from the root folder masked as a subfolder.

Example.

When I open domain.com/test/ I need to show the same content as domain.com

When I open domain.com/test/option1/ I need to show the same content as domain.com/option1/

I've tried multiple htaccess options but I couldn't make it work.

Is this possible?
Thanks

UPDATE

I added this to the .htacces file inside test folder

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ test/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Kindly do add your tried .htaccess rules file in your question, thank you.

Comment: RavinderSingh13 There it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setup is wrong in two aspects:

1. the location of the distributed configuration file (".htaccess"), you need to place it in the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder of that http host, not inside the `/test` folder.
2. You need to implement the rewriting logic the other way round:

This should do what you want to achieve:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?test/(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

You should generally prefer to implement such rules in the actual http server's host configuration. If you do not have access to that (for example if you are using a cheap hosting provider), then you can indeed use a *distributed* configuration file. The rule is implemented such that it will work likewise.

Whether the condition you implemented is actually required depends on your setup: if you have multiple http hosts your server offers then this *might* be required if the hosts have different logic. Otherwise you can simply remove it.

Comment: Hey arkascha, can you help me with this?
I need the same you explained but on a subfolder.
Ex:
example.com/subfolder/
example.com/subfolder/test/

Comment: @yom Then what keeps you from adapting this solution to your setup?

Comment: I don't understand the RewriteCond and It's very difficult to find documentation about that.
I've tried:
^(www\.)?example\.com\subfolder\$
But it didn't work

Maybe it should be?:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subfolder$

Comment: @yom The documentation of the apache modules is right there: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond  As typical for OpenSource software it is of excellent quality and comes with great examples.

Comment: @yom Looks like you need to read about what `%{HTTP_HOST}` actually is.

Comment: I've been reading but I can't make it work.
I think I must use %{REQUEST_URI} instead of %{HTTP_HOST} but I can´t solve it.
Can you give me a hand again? This is what i've got:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test(.*)
RewriteRule ^/?test/(.*)$ /$1 [L]

Comment: I created a chat room for this exchange, since it has nothing to do with the answer above: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249739/htaccess-mask-subfolder-as-root

Comment: Hey Arkascha, thanks for being so patient. I can´t talk in the chat beacause I don´t have 20 reputation. I'll explain it here more specifically. I have this physical folder https://www.example.com.ar/testing/cotizador/ and I need to see exactly the same in https://www.example.com.ar/testing/cotizador/sandbox/ (sandbox folder doesn´t exist)

Comment: OK, so you actually have a different situation than what had been discussed in this question. Kind of the other way round.

Comment: I'd say that should work: `RewriteRule ^/?testing/cotizador/sandbox(.*)$ /testing/cotizador$1 [END]`. You won't need a `RewriteCond` at all if you serve only a single host ("domain").

Comment: Otherwise please ask a separate question so that your issue can be answered and discussed.